# Crystal debugging with GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, crystal-lang

I am trying to learn to debug programs written in Crystal with GDB. Here is a sample:

```
class Demo
  @array = [] of String

  def bar(url)
    ret = url.downcase * 2
    if ret == "alsj"
      return false
    else
      return ret
    end
  end

  def do(foo)
    @array.push(foo)
    html = bar(foo)
    puts "HI" # GDB breakpoint here
    return html
  end
end

a = Demo.new
puts a.do("HI")
```

I compiled the sample above with the `--debug` flag and loaded it into GDB. Then I let it run and stopped at the marked line (`GDB breakpoint here`). Now I have <s>three</s> four questions:

1. **Printing string values (e.g. `foo`):**
   When I inspect a string variable, I often see something like `$1 = (struct String *) 0x4b9f18`. When I say `printf "%s", foo`, I get nothing back. How can I display the current value of a string variable?
2. **optimized out.**
   Other times I just see `$1 = <optimized out>` when inspecting a variable. What does that mean and how can I see the value in that case?
3. **Accessing object variables**
   How can I see the value of `@array` in the given situation? `p array` says no symbol in current context and `p @array` returns unknown address space modifier.
   **Edit:** I found a way: use `p self.array`
4. **Vanished variables**
   In the given situation (breaking at the line `puts "HI"`) I can't see the variable html at all: `p html` returns no symbol in current context. Why is that and how do I solve it?

Comment: Not a comment on GDB debugging, but Ary presented a preview of an interactive debugger (like Pry in Ruby). It is not released yet, but potentially it will make gdb debugging less relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520143/783510

Answer (score 6):

Crystal debugging capabilities are still [on development](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4457) so you can't see some symbols or symbols data is optimized by LLVM. About *optimized output*, sometimes crystal algorithms are optimized too much, even on `--debug` builds. By example:

Currently yield methods are [inlined](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/attributes.html) and optimized, so this isn't very debuggable.

```
3.times do |i|
  pp i
end
```

However, you can use `pp` keyword to print `name => value`.

```
pp i
i => 1
i => 2
i => 3
```

Also you can set breakpoints using `debugger` keyword and inspect macro output using `{% debug() %}` or `$ crystal tool expand` command.

On the other hand compound statement are easy to debug using tools like GDB.

```
i = 0
while i < 3
  debugger
  i += 1 # i variable is listed by GDB
end
```

Finally you can try some tricks I found in my debugging daily tasks.

1. **Printing string values:** try `@[NoInline]` and `p &foo.c` this will enable args data and you will be able to print all struct string value

Using `@[NoInline]` attribute:

```
@[NoInline]
def do(foo)
  debugger
end
```

On GDB:

```
(gdb) p &foo.c
$1 = (UInt8 *) 0x10008e6c4 "HI"
```

2. **optimized out:** maybe because LLVM optimizes some method calls. if you see `<optimized out>` use `@[NoInline]` and try assigning instance vars to local vars `array = @array`
3. **Accessing object variables:** use `self.var` for instance vars.

Also use `p array.buffer[0]@size` to print array values.

```
(gdb) p &array.buffer[0].c
$19 = (UInt8 *) 0x10008e7f4 "HI"
```

4. **Vanished variables:** this happens because debugging info is not complete enough.

Try adding debug info manually converting or casting values:

```
@[NoInline]
def do(foo)
  html = bar(foo).as(String)
  html = bar(foo).to_s
  debugger
end
```

Now html var is visible on GDB thanks to `.as` or `.to_s` methods

```
(gdb) p &html.c
$1 = (UInt8 *) 0x1002fcfec "hihi"
```